# p:dataTable does not paginate

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, pagination

I have a paginated data table:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="proj" value="#{orderListView.projects}"
                 paginator="true" rows="3"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
    >
        <p:column sortBy="#{proj.id}">
            <h:outputText value="#{proj.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column  sortBy="#{proj.name}">
            <h:outputText value="#{proj.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{proj.displayName}">
            <h:outputText value="#{proj.displayName}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Which is based on this entity:

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String displayName;
    private String name;

    public Project() {}

    public Project(int id, String displayName, String name) {
        this.id = id; 
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Getters+setters.
}
```

And is populated in this bean (for brevity, I have omitted the DAO/Service part and I am hardcoding the model in `@PostConstruct`):

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OrderListView {

    private List<Project> projects;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
        projects.add(new Project(10, "Cruze", "cruze"));
        projects.add(new Project(11, "Dark-Hive", "dark-hive"));
        projects.add(new Project(12, "Delta", "delta"));
        projects.add(new Project(10, "Cruze", "cruze"));
        projects.add(new Project(11, "Dark-Hive", "dark-hive"));
        projects.add(new Project(12, "Delta", "delta"));
        projects.add(new Project(13, "Dot-Luv", "dot-luv"));
        projects.add(new Project(14, "Eggplant", "eggplant"));
        projects.add(new Project(15, "Excite-Bike", "excite-bike"));
        projects.add(new Project(16, "Flick", "flick"));
        projects.add(new Project(17, "Glass-X", "glass-x"));
        projects.add(new Project(18, "Cruze", "cruze"));
        projects.add(new Project(19, "Dark-Hive", "dark-hive"));
        projects.add(new Project(20, "Delta", "delta"));
        projects.add(new Project(23, "Dot-Luv", "dot-luv"));
        projects.add(new Project(24, "Eggplant", "eggplant"));
        projects.add(new Project(25, "Excite-Bike", "excite-bike"));
        projects.add(new Project(26, "Flick", "flick"));
        projects.add(new Project(27, "Glass-X", "glass-x"));
    }

    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }
}
```

The data table correctly shows the list, but pagination doesn't work. How is this caused and how can I solve it? I also tried lazy loading, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: "*I use Sprimg MVC and PrimeFaces.*" - untrue. You cannot use them together (PrimeFaces as a JSF component library).

Comment: I am sorry, Spring Core -I`ve changed

Comment: For lazy loading, you need to created lazyDateModel for Project and implement you own load method ... You example is not even close to it. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

Comment: Yes, I take it from official site, but in my case it does not work. Now I try create basic table with only pagination(without lazy), but pagination does not work - data loads and pages are exists at table(unworking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong on your end, but I copied your code into a testproject and the paginator works just fine with PrimeFaces 5.2.

Comment: really, I delete bootstrap and bootsfaces dependencies and pagination is working now!

Comment: That's great to hear! Please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. It would probably be good to include bootstrap into the tags of the question, maybe others encounter that same issue in the future.

Comment: Not only include bootsfaces as a tagbut also in the question itself